# How SignalR group works internally? Why it is faster to send message to group with multiple client?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

People recommend to use signalR groups, when multiple clients are interested in same kind of message. I am bit curious, how this concept internally works. Why sending message through SignalR group to multiple clients are faster than sending it to individually client?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below link for details on how SignalR works -

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/real-time-web-applications-with-signalr

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a noticeable enough performance difference, there is more coding involved in being able to send to an individual, because you should to get their connectionId and code for that extra layer of code, rather than just dumping them into their own group, and broadcasting to that group even if it only contains a single client.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! If that is the case, we can have groups for all kind of subscriptions, even if we are subscribing to the event which are user specific and will not be shared.